# A Button to remove an item from the order in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I’m looking for a way of adding a button next to each item that will delete it from the order.

The template is: `woocommerce/order/order-details-item.php`

I found a function to use, which is: `wc_delete_order_item()`

It removes all the items if I add it inside the loop.

However how do I run the function on a click of a button? I’ve tried using ajax however having `wc_delete_order_item()` in an external file comes up with ***"Undefined function"***.

Please help.

Comment: Yes I will try to help, of course …

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thank you. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First (just to fix things) the template `order-details-item.php`   is used in:

- Order received page (Thankyou)
- My account view order pages

Now to use [**`wc_delete_order_item()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_delete_order_item.html#62-84) you need the item ID as argument.

You could use a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_order_item_meta_end`** action hook to display a functional button to remove order items, instead of overriding the template, but it will remove the order item and will need to be refreshed a second time.

Visually you will get that:

[image]

Here is this partial code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'display_remove_order_item_button', 10, 3 );
function display_remove_order_item_button( $item_id, $item, $order ){
    // Avoiding displaying buttons on email notification
    if( ! ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' ) || is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) ) return;

    if( isset($_POST["remove_item_$item_id"]) && $_POST["remove_item_$item_id"] == 'Remove this item' ){
        wc_delete_order_item( $item_id );
    }

    echo '<form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style= "margin-top:12px;">
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="remove_item_'.$item_id.'" value="Remove this item" />
    </form>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

It will remove the order item.

Also you should need to use the `WC_Abstract_Order` method [`calculate_totals()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#1118-1158) to refresh/calculate the new order totals:

```
$order->calculate_totals();
```

> **But the best and completely functional way** should be **to use Ajax**, which is much more **complicated**, and a real development.
>
> To use correctly Ajax here, you should need to add a hidden field with the Item ID, to get it with ajax and give it to your PHP function (the missing argument, to make **`wc_delete_order_item()`** working fine without any error) and also the Order ID…

Now next time, if your try the Ajax way, you should ask a new question adding to it your own code, explaining what is working and what not…

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. What you've posted is completely fine. I don't need to Ajax solution. Also I don't need to recalculate the total as my products are all free. How would I go about refreshing the cart after the item's been removed?

Comment: @Adrian To refresh the cart you should need some jQuery/javascript… You should ask a new question with the code that you are using now, because answering in comments is not the way when is long with code and explanations useful for others… Once done notify me here.

Comment: The form seems to refresh the page (as it's the default behaviour), but the item isn't removed until you manually refresh again. However if I do 'preventDefault' on the form, then the item doesn't get removed because preventDefault stops the function from running. Also if you apply a delay and refresh the page in JQuery (on click of the button) then it doesn't work because the page gets reloaded first (by submitting the form) so your delay never actually executes. Any idea what would the solution be? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Adrian I know, It's mentioned in my answer and that's why you should do it in Ajax like I am telling you at the end of this answer… So you should better get your initial Ajax code and whith my hooked function you should add 2 hidden fields, one for the item ID and one for the Order ID… With javascript you will be able to send those IDs to your php function through wordpress Ajax… then make `wc_delete_order_item( $item_id )` and `$order->calculate_totals();` working correcly.

Comment: Thanks for that. Would you be able to help me with the ajax solution please? Do I keep the function in functions.php? How do I reference it in the ajax call? Thank you